# How to serialize String to an existed ByteBuffer efficiently?

Tags: java, string, bytebuffer

It seems that `String.getBytes()` will create a new byte array, so there is an extra memory copy. Can I encode a String directly to a `ByteBuffer` without an intermediate byte array?

for example:

```
void putString(ByteBuffer bb, String s) {
    byte[] arr = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    bb.put(arr);
}
```

This piece of code will create a byte array, encode the string to this byte array, then copy the content of byte array to ByteBuffer. 
I think the byte array is not necessary, it will bring GC and extra memory copy.

Comment: I don't want to create the intermediate byte array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`CharsetEncoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) to write directly to a `ByteBuffer`:

```
static void putString(ByteBuffer buffer, String str, Charset charset) {
    CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();
    encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(str), buffer, true);
    encoder.flush(buffer);
}
```

It's your responsibility to make sure enough space has been allocated. You can also check the result of the [`encode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#encode(java.nio.CharBuffer,%20java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20boolean)) method to see if it was successful.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a simple way to completely eliminate intermediate byte arrays.

However if you're worrying about this because the String is huge, you can break it into chunks:

```
  for(offset=0; offset<str.length(); offset+=chunkSize) {
      String chunk = str.substring(offset, offset+chunkSize);
      byteBuffer.put(chunk.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  }
```

However, if your input strings are huge enough that this optimisation is necessary, the overall architecture of your program is probably ill-conceived.

You should *not* worry about GC performance unless you've seen something unusual while profiling. The JRE is *brilliant* at efficient GC.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. String objects don't have encoding.

Answer (score 0):

String objects are immutable by purpose. The whole idea of that class is to *not* allow to manipulate any underlying data structures (mainly for security and performance optimization reasons).

In that sense: there is no other better approach to acquire bytes making up a string object in Java.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: The answer is: no such thing. I reworded, hope it is more clear now.